# Android - Crash report notification

Tags: android, exception, bug-reporting

How can I show notification that shows when the application crashed (or service crashed), and if the user click on it, it send the StackTrace by email?
I saw some applications that do that.

Comment: you saw some applications right? Then what is the problem?

Comment: How can I do that by myself? I saw applications that I downloaded from the market, not their source code...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Make your own class by extending the interface `UncaughtExceptionHandler`

```
public class UnCaughtException implements UncaughtExceptionHandler
{
    private Context context;
    private static Context context1;

    public UnCaughtException(Context ctx)
    {
        context = ctx;
        context1 = ctx;
    }

    private StatFs getStatFs()
    {
        File path = Environment.getDataDirectory();
        return new StatFs(path.getPath());
    }

    private long getAvailableInternalMemorySize(StatFs stat)
    {
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long availableBlocks = stat.getAvailableBlocks();
        return availableBlocks * blockSize;
    }

    private long getTotalInternalMemorySize(StatFs stat)
    {
        long blockSize = stat.getBlockSize();
        long totalBlocks = stat.getBlockCount();
        return totalBlocks * blockSize;
    }

    private void addInformation(StringBuilder message)
    {
        message.append("Locale: ").append(Locale.getDefault()).append('\n');
        try
        {
            PackageManager pm = context.getPackageManager();
            PackageInfo pi;
            pi = pm.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 0);
            message.append("Version: ").append(pi.versionName).append('\n');
            message.append("Package: ").append(pi.packageName).append('\n');
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            Log.e("CustomExceptionHandler", "Error", e);
            message.append("Could not get Version information for ").append(context.getPackageName());
        }
        message.append("Phone Model: ").append(android.os.Build.MODEL).append('\n');
        message.append("Android Version: ").append(android.os.Build.VERSION.RELEASE).append('\n');
        message.append("Board: ").append(android.os.Build.BOARD).append('\n');
        message.append("Brand: ").append(android.os.Build.BRAND).append('\n');
        message.append("Device: ").append(android.os.Build.DEVICE).append('\n');
        message.append("Host: ").append(android.os.Build.HOST).append('\n');
        message.append("ID: ").append(android.os.Build.ID).append('\n');
        message.append("Model: ").append(android.os.Build.MODEL).append('\n');
        message.append("Product: ").append(android.os.Build.PRODUCT).append('\n');
        message.append("Type: ").append(android.os.Build.TYPE).append('\n');
        StatFs stat = getStatFs();
        message.append("Total Internal memory: ").append(getTotalInternalMemorySize(stat)).append('\n');
        message.append("Available Internal memory: ").append(getAvailableInternalMemorySize(stat)).append('\n');
    }

    @Override
    public void uncaughtException(Thread t, Throwable e)
    {
        try
        {
            StringBuilder report = new StringBuilder();
            Date curDate = new Date();
            report.append("Error Report collected on : ").append(curDate.toString()).append('\n').append('\n');
            report.append("Informations :").append('\n');
            addInformation(report);
            report.append('\n').append('\n');
            report.append("Stack:\n");
            final Writer result = new StringWriter();
            final PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter(result);
            e.printStackTrace(printWriter);
            report.append(result.toString());
            printWriter.close();
            report.append('\n');
            report.append("**** End of current Report ***");
            Log.e(UnCaughtException.class.getName(), "Error while sendErrorMail" + report);
            sendErrorMail(report);
        }
        catch ( Throwable ignore )
        {
            Log.e(UnCaughtException.class.getName(), "Error while sending error e-mail", ignore);
        }
    }

    /**
     * This method for call alert dialog when application crashed!
     */
    public void sendErrorMail(final StringBuilder errorContent)
    {
        final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
        new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                Looper.prepare();
                builder.setTitle("Sorry...!");
                builder.create();
                builder.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                builder.setPositiveButton("Report", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {
                        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                        String subject = "Your App crashed! Fix it!";
                        StringBuilder body = new StringBuilder("Yoddle");
                        body.append('\n').append('\n');
                        body.append(errorContent).append('\n').append('\n');
                        // sendIntent.setType("text/plain");
                        sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[] { "yourmail@domain.com" });
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, body.toString());
                        sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
                        sendIntent.setType("message/rfc822");
                        context1.startActivity(sendIntent);
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                });
                builder.setMessage("Oops,Your application has crashed");
                builder.show();
                Looper.loop();
            }
        }.start();
    }
}
```

Set the CustomExceptionHandler as the `DefaultExceptionHandler` in your MainActivity

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler(new UnCaughtException(MainActivity.this));
        int y = 5 / 0;
    }
}
```

**Note :**

The above example code sends a email with the crash data. You can modify it to meet your need.

Answer (score 1):

you can use [ACRA](http://acra.ch/) library. From the doc

> Acra catches exceptions, retrieves lots of context data and send them
>   to a Google Spreadsheet... or whatever backend you prefer.

or [Crittercism](https://www.crittercism.com/). It supports

> 1. Error Monitoring
> 2. App Monitoring

Comment: I prefer not to use external libraries